# Advanced Search by minimum/maximum values

Tags: search, meta-query

I'm building an advanced search form which allows me to search by different parameters. Currently, searching by taxonomies work fine. My issue occurs with trying to set a minimum price to search by. Here's the code in my functions.php file:

```
function advanced_search_query($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', array( 'properties' ));

        if (isset($_GET['propertyfor'])) {
            $query->set('taxonomy', 'propertyfor');
            $query->set('terms', $_GET['propertyfor']);
        }

        if (isset($_GET['propertytype'])) {
            $query->set('taxonomy', 'propertytype');
            $query->set('terms', $_GET['propertytype']);
        }

        if (isset($_GET['minPrice'])) {
            $query->set('meta_query', array(
                'key' => 'shru_price',
                'value' => $_GET['minPrice'],
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
            ));
        }
    };
    return $query;
};
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'advanced_search_query', 1000);
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use a meta query to handle it but nothing is happening. The minimum price is completely ignored when displaying results.

Anyone know how to fix?

Edit: FYI, the numeric values are stored in the database without any special characters.

UPDATE: It works for the following, where i set a min and max value and use BETWEEN:

```
    if (isset($_GET['minPrice']) && isset($_GET['maxPrice'])) {
        $query->set('meta_query', array(
            array(
                'key' => 'shru_price',
                'value' => array($_GET['minPrice'], $_GET['maxPrice']),
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
            )
        ));
    }
```

but not for what I originally posted where only one is set and i use `>=` or `<=`. I used elseif statements between each but still no results were being produced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A `meta_query` is an ***array of arrays***. You only have an array.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
    $query->set('meta_query', array(
        'key' => 'shru_price',
        'value' => $_GET['minPrice'],
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    ));
```

It should be:

```
$query->set(
  'meta_query', 
  array(
    array(
      'key' => 'shru_price',
      'value' => $_GET['minPrice'],
      'compare' => '>=',
      'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    )
  )
);
```

And please validate/sanitize that user supplied data before using it !

Comment: you beat me by 12 secs :) ...

Comment: @G.M. : Interesting that we both reformatted the code in (almost) the same way :)

Comment: you certainly do earn your reputation ^_^

Comment: I updated the post with an interesting issue. Any idea of the cause behind it?

Comment: The SQL come out correct when I test `>=`. I don't know what to say about that secondary issue.

Comment: using just a single value such as minPrice? hmm, no idea why this isn't working for me then